# Object properties are lost

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to use an object `GestionnaireDesTaches` in a php script that I call after clicking on a button in my website.
this is how I call the script :

```
$(document).on( "click", "#addWidgetButton", function(e) {
                 e.preventDefault(); 
                 gridster[0].add_widget.apply(gridster[0], ['<li data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="gs-w"><header><p style="cursor: move;">|||</p><div class="dragDiv">New</div></header></li>', 1, 1]); 
                 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'trait.php',
                    data: { action : action , board : board  },
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert("Project created!");
                    }
                });
            });
```

This is working fine, but I have a problem with the script :

```
    <?php
        require_once('GestionnaireDesTaches.php');
        require_once('Board.php');
        require_once('Projet.php');
        require_once('Tache.php');

        $boards = simplexml_load_file('gtxml.xml');
        $gestionnaireDesTaches = new GestionnaireDesTaches($boards['utilisateur']);

        ?> <p> <?php echo "hh".$gestionnaireDesTaches->getUtilisateur();?></p><?php   
        ?> <p> <?php echo "hh".$boards['utilisateur'];?></p>
```

the first echo gives me nothing, the second one shows me the Utilisateur, it's like the object loses its properties when called the second time (`$gestionnaireDesTaches->getUtilisateur();` ) There is no problem with loading the xml file, and the class works perfectly when I run it alone : this how I test it alone :

```
$gt = new GestionnaireDesTaches("Othman");
echo $gt->getUtilisateur();  \\ I get my name with this
```

Please tell me what Am doing wrong !

Comment: can you provide the code from `gtxml.xml` please

Comment: axiac's answer works, thank you anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem comes from the fact that your class `GestionnaireDesTaches` expects a string as constructor parameter but it gets an object of type [`SimpleXmlElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php).

The function [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) returns a object of type [`SimpleXmlElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) which is a wrapper around a PHP resource that contains the XML object. All the methods of `SimpleXmlElement` that provide access to the information stored in the XML object return `SimpleXmlElement` objects.

That means `$boards['utilisateur']` is not a string but a `SimpleXmlElement` object that (most of the times) behaves like a string when you expect it behave like a string. I cannot tell why it doesn't work this way in this fragment of code because I don't know how you handle it inside the `GestionnaireDesTaches` class.

Try to convert `$boards['utilisateur']` to string before passing it to the constructor of class `GestionnaireDesTaches`:

```
$gestionnaireDesTaches = new GestionnaireDesTaches(
    (string)$boards['utilisateur']
);
```

or

```
$gestionnaireDesTaches = new GestionnaireDesTaches(
    $boards['utilisateur']->__toString()
);
```